# C++ objects outputs with attribute name as a string

Tags: c++, class

```
class myFun(Employee obj, String attribute)
{
   //return proper attribute value without using conditions like If-Else, ternary or     
   // conditional operators like && etc.
}
```

Now if i call:

```
myFun(obj, “name”);
```

then this function should return name of Employee from object “obj” which was passed as parameter. So based on name of attribute value, it should return that object’s attribute value.

is there any way to do it in c++ without using if conditions or switch statements? i know in python we can use getattr.

Comment: Are you using a C++-framework? There is no `Object` in C++. How is `Employee` defined?

Comment: If it's a requirement to access attributes by name, you should consider using a `std::map` instead.

Comment: sorry for the object part.. its a class basically

Answer (score 3):

You will need to implement your own [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)-like behavior. You could for instance have a map inside the object into which you register the name of each attribute, and perhaps a functor to get the value (or something).

In other words, it's doable, but not supported by the language so it won't be short, simple, automatic or necessarily very intuitive to other readers of your code.

Comment: can you provide me some sample codes where this has been implemented efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ doesn't have reflection, so without a conditional it's not doable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without changing the structure of your class.
If performance is not critical, here is a workaround:

```
class Employee{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> attributes;
    /*SNIP*/
    public:
    void addAttr(std::string attr, std::string value){ attributes[attr] = value; }
    std::string getValue(std::string attr){ return attributes[attr]; }
    //Use this function if you are using c++11 compiler: std::string getValue(std::string attr){ return attributes.at(attr); }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need list there?

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is possible in C++, though indirectly ;)

Some of the article related to this...

http://lcgapp.cern.ch/project/architecture/ReflectionPaper.pdf
http://replicaisland.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/building-reflective-object-system-in-c.html
http://www.vollmann.com/pubs/meta/meta/meta.html

So you an achieve that behvaior with reflection! And of course these article contains example which you can use to start with, feel free to share any questions.

You can also give try to BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT http://boost-spirit.com/dl_more/fusion_v2/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/extension/macros/adapt_struct.html